# probability of at least 4 Tails

Tags: probability

You flip a weighted coin that comes up Heads 30% of the time and Tails 70%. If you flip this coin 6 times, what is the probability that you see at least 4 Tails?

Would someone please check if my solution is correct?
I know there is going to be $2^6 = 64$ different possible outcomes. There will be three different acceptable outcomes,
any sequence that contain 4 Tails which there are ${6 \choose 4} = 15$

and any sequence that contain 5 Tails which there are ${6 \choose 5} = 6$

and any sequence that contain 6 Tails which there are ${6 \choose 6} = 1$

I then multiplied 15 by the probability of 4 T and 2 H which $15 * (0.7)^4 * (0.3)^2 = 0.324135$

multiplied 6 by the probability of 5 T and 1 H which $6 * (0.7)^5 * (0.3) = 0.302526$

multiplied 1 by the probability of 6 T and 0 H which $1 * (0.7)^6 = 0.117649$

Finally I took the sum of the last three results to get $0.74431$

Is it okay that I got each probability individually and just added them together??

I would be very grateful if someone can confirm if this solution is correct or something is missing.

Comment: it is correct .

Comment: @stochs Thanks for your confirmation.